# Inclusive range between an inclusive range

Tags: mysql, sql, intervals, between, hour

I'm trying to **compare an inclusve interval of hours with another** so that I can figure out if the first one is inside or half in the second one or vice versa.
This is the code I made:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM dates
 WHERE dates.hourA1 
   AND dates.hourA2 BETWEEN dates.hourB1 AND dates.hourB2
```

This code works like a Venn diagram. On one hand I have the collection of all hours between hourA1 and hourA2 and on the other hand the collection of all hours between hourB1 and hourB2. What I want is to count how many records have hours in common in each collection.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM dates d
 WHERE d.hourA1 BETWEEN d.hourB1 AND d.hourB2
    OR d.hourA2 BETWEEN d.hourB1 AND d.hourB2
    OR d.hourB1 BETWEEN d.hourA1 AND d.hourA2
    OR d.hourB2 BETWEEN d.hourA1 AND d.hourA2
```

I also added a SQLFiddle with some testdata for you:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/99fc3/1

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but your code although it works on most of cases, it ignores this situation: [link](http://www.mentorials.com/site/monographs/high-school/mathematics/images/venn-diagram-subset.png) Imagine that collection B are all the hours between hourA1 and hourA2 AND that A are all the hours between hourB1 and hourB2. In this case that might not work.

Comment: I didn't know that website existed. It looks pretty good to discuss this kind of things. Anyway, I saw your code in action. One thing I dont understand is why it only counts 2 of them?

Comment: Nevermind, I didnt check properly the second record you added. So, it works on those cases

Comment: the second inserted row
hourA1 = '2016-01-01' hourA2='2016-09-30' hourB1='2016-10-31' hourB2='2018-05-30'
so the two time-ranges are not overlapping. if i undstood right, you just want to count overlapping timenbands

Comment: This your code dealing with the case I told you earlier: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d568b/2/0

Comment: I'm sorry for not giving you the correct answer as soon as you updated, but I wasn't with my pc around to test on the application I'm creating. I tested it out and It works fine. Regarding to your answer, my question wasn't totally completed at the time you answer, but if you checked the Venn Diagram thing you probably would notice what I really wanted you to answer. The "vice versa" I added after didn't do much a diffrence since I already explained myself the best I could with Math collections.

Comment: @DormiréparaTolos you're welcome - no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dates
WHERE dates.hourA1 BETWEEN dates.hourB1 AND dates.hourB2
OR dates.hourA2 BETWEEN dates.hourB1 AND dates.hourB2
OR dates.hourB1 BETWEEN dates.hourA1 AND dates.hourA2
OR dates.hourB2 BETWEEN dates.hourA1 AND dates.hourA2
```

Comment: you don't need 4 different conditions - just two of them, like i showed should do the same.